# Random enumerator error when using DO End loops

Tags: ruby

Any thoughts on why the following code outputs the contents of the {bracket} code but not the "do" code?

```
my_array = ["alpha", "beta", "gamma"]
puts my_array.collect {
    |word|
    word.capitalize
}
puts "======================"
puts my_array.collect do |word| word.capitalize end
puts "=========END=========="
```

When executed the code returns the following as the output

```
Alpha
Beta
Gamma
======================
#<Enumerator:0x2517ed0>
======================
```

Any and all help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`do ... end` and `{}` block syntaxes have different precedence - a block defined using braces binds tighter to its caller than one using `do ... end`, which is why your first example works as intended.

Edit: Elaborating a bit: When you use `puts my_array.collect {|word| word.capitalize}`, you're sending to `puts` the result of `my_array.collect {|word| word.capitalize}` - the array resulting from capitalizing each item in the original array. When you use `puts my_array.collect do |word| word.capitalize end`, you're passing the value of `my_array.collect` - an enumerator - to `puts`, and ALSO passing the block to `puts`. Since `puts` doesn't `yield` to the block, you end up writing the string representation of your enumerator to `$stdout`, and the block never gets called. Ergo, it's a good idea to use parenthesis when using blocks like this, unless you (and anyone you're working on the code with!) knows exactly what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

Because it's evaluating this:

```
puts my_array.collect

=> #<Enumerator:0x000001009efce0>
```

This, works as you intended:

```
puts( my_array.collect do |word| word.capitalize end )

=> Alpha 
=> Beta 
=> Gamma
```

Most people tend to spread the `do` syntax out over several lines.